# SceneKit: stop animation of particle system

Tags: scenekit, particle-system

I am using a SCNPArticleSystem to create a haze around an object.  Once the haze has been created, I don't want it it change further.

I'm noticing that the particle system animation is continuing after the emissionDuration has been reached. This causes the app to use a lot of CPU.

Is there a way to freeze the particle system as it exists after the emissionDuration and not have any further animation hit?

I have tried calling:

```
particleSyste.removeAllAnimations()
```

But that doesn't help.  Here is how I set up the particle system

```
    let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()

    particleSystem.particleImage = UIImage(named: "smoke")
    particleSystem.particleColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.005)
    particleSystem.birthRate = 10000;
    particleSystem.birthDirection = .random
    particleSystem.birthLocation = .volume
    particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    particleSystem.particleSize = 2
    particleSystem.particleSizeVariation = 0.2
    particleSystem.particleAngleVariation = 360
    particleSystem.blendMode = .additive
    particleSystem.orientationMode = .free
    particleSystem.emissionDuration = 1
    particleSystem.loops = false
    particleSystem.warmupDuration = 2
    particleSystem.isLocal = true
    particleSystem.stretchFactor = 1.5

    let particleSystemGeometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.85 * GAL_IMAGE_WIDTH_IN_LIGHT_YEARS * sceneScale / 2, height: 100 * sceneScale)
    particleSystem.emitterShape = particleSystemGeometry
    particleSystemNode = SCNNode(geometry: particleSystemGeometry)
    particleSystemNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)
    particleSystemNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
    particleSystemNode.name = "ParticleNode"

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(particleSystemNode)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally contact Apple DTS about this issue.  They confirmed that there is no way to prevent this.  When you add a particle system to the Scene, it turns on continuous rendering.  They suggested submitting a bug on it (which I will).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no...  I don't think there is a way to freeze it in it's current state.  There is a fog component for the scene, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

The particle system wants to run its course based on the behavior you give it.  One thought would be to loop it continuously, reduce your birthrate, 0 warmupDuration, and reduce particleSize.

Something like:
birthRate < 100, warmupDuration = 0, particleSize 0.15, 
particleLifeSpan < 10 seconds, emmisionDuration 3.5

So that...  N birthrates occur over a 3.5 second period and last for < 10 seconds to give it some residue.

I use similar settings for a smoke trail, but if you set the desired vectors for direction, I "think" it will produce something in the neighborhood of what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions.  Yeah, fog is not what I need here.  I need the "haze" to be surrounding a particular object  I took the above code, changed particleSystem.loops to true and then added a code block that get executed 5 seconds later.  This block sets the birthrate to 0 and the emissionDuration to 0.  Unfortunately, this did not help.  It is still using 50% of the CPU on the iPad after the code block runs.  I'm really surprised there is no way to do this.

Comment: Hmm.  The particleSystem is a bit quirky too.  I do a removeAllParticleSystems to clear things out, but I have not looked at the CPU after stopping it.  Sry